# Bash: troubles with find--not finding existing files

Tags: bash, terminal

Not sure what mistake I am making, but `find` is not returning anything. What is wrong with my syntax? I have consulted several online resources and my syntax seems identical to the suggested commands.

Example:

```
~$ find /home/foo/ -name bar
~$ sudo find /home/foo/ -name bar
```

Both return nothing, when there are files meeting the search criteria within the directory.

This is on Ubuntu 12.

Comment: You do know, that you search for a file named **exactly** bar, not foobar or barfly? Else you would need find `/home/foo/ -name '*bar*'`

Comment: @EugenRieck No, I didn't. The resources I used didn't mention that, so I figured it was just the file name. Thanks. Post it as an answer if you want points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tripping point is, that `find /home/foo/ -name bar` will search for a file **exactly** named `bar`, and will not find `foobar` or `barfly`. If you want to search for a part of the filename, you have to use wildcards (most oftne `*`). Be aware, that shell expansion is likely to fiddle with your wildcard patterns, so use quoting: `find /home/foo/ -name '*bar*'`